# Powershell ImportExcel and skip/exclude specific sheets

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

I have the code below for importing a workbook, exclude specific worksheets in the workbook, work on some conditions and then export a single worksheet. Everything works except that it doesn't exclude some of the worksheets specified in the "Get-ExcelSheetInfo" line.

```
$param = @{
    Path = $inputfileName
    StartRow = 5
    HeaderName = 'Setting', 'Current settings', 'Proposed settings', 'Notes'
}
# Loop and obtain worksheets in workbook
Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path $inputfileName | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "Sheet1" -and $_.Name -notlike "Sheet3" -and $_.Name -notlike "Sheet5" -and $_.Name -notlike "Sheet8" -and $_.Name -notlike "Sheet11" -and $_.Name -notlike "Change Record" -and $_.Name -notlike "LIST"} | ForEach-Object {
    # Set the worksheetname name in $param
    $param['WorksheetName'] = $_.Name
    # Import the worksheet and enumerate it
    foreach($line in Import-Excel @param) {
        $currSettings = $line.'Current settings'
        $propSettings = $line.'Proposed settings'
        # If the value of 'Current Settings' cell is equal to the adjacent value of
        # 'Proposed Settings' cell OR is empty (white spaces), skip and go to next iteration
        if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings)) {
            continue
        }
        # If we're here, condition before this was not true, hence we want to
        # Output the line (row) and add a new column (A) with the name of the worksheet the setting was obtained from
        $line | Select-Object @{N='Workstream';E={$param['WorksheetName']}}, *
    } 
} | Export-Excel -Path $outputfileName -WorksheetName 'Change List' -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -TableName table1 -TableStyle Medium6 -FreezeTopRow -CellStyleSB {
param($workSheet)
$WorkSheet.Cells["C:D"].Style.HorizontalAlignment="Center"}
```

I'm wondering if it may be because some of those sheets are matching conditions from "if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings)) { continue"
even though I'm specifying that they should not be imported from the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: The code you have looks good to me, though you're using `-notlike` but no wildcards (ie `*`) if youre looking for exact match use `-ne`, otherwise, add wildcards to your RHS of the comparison

Comment: Btw nice one with `-CellStyleSB` i wasn't aware of that parameter

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried that and it still inserts some of the sheets. I even moved the cmdlet to the "if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings))" and changed it to

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks! I tried that and it still inserts some of the sheets. I even moved the cmdlet to the "if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings))" and changed it to: if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings) -or $_.Name -eq "Sheet1" -and $_.Name -like "*Sheet3*" -and $_.Name -eq "Sheet5" -and $_.Name -eq "Sheet8" -and $_.Name -eq "Sheet11" -and $_.Name -eq "Change Record" -and $_.Name -eq "LIST") {

Still gives me the same output. No clue why.

Comment: Have you tried running `Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path $inputfileName` alone and double checked the worksheet name you're using to exclude are correct?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I did. And the funny thing is when I use the where-object it outputs the right ones. So that why I'm wondering if somewhere along the "if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings))" is pulling it back in because those sheets have those headers as well. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong in the code. You can even though ineffective, add the where-object condition at the end of the loop before export-excel, since you are creating a Workstream column you could use that for filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to have stemmed from the way the file was launching with an "invoke-item" cmdlet I had in place. I removed that line and used "- Show" at the end of the Export and it's outputting properly now. Not sure how or why that caused an issue.